# How to use jQuery on-page HTML stored in the object?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get page HTML by .html() and store it in variable contents. I want to perform some operations on this HTML like removing scroll bars before sending it to a method that prints it.

I have tried using the replace method to remove overflow properties by replacing them with a blank on the HTML object, but I am not sure whether it is the right way to do it. I was wondering if I can use a jQuery function on this HTML and use .css to remove the styles of some divs.

```
var contents = divToPrint.html();
```

I want to do something like this if its possible:

```
$(contents).find(span).css('overflow: hidden auto;', '')
```

instead of using following code:

```
contents = contents.replace('overflow: hidden auto;', '')
contents = contents.replace('overflow-y: auto;', '')
contents = contents.replace('-ms-overflow-x: hidden;', '')
contents = contents.replace('-ms-overflow-y: auto;', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
var contents = divToPrint.html();
```

`contents` is now a string - you need to convert this to a jquery object:

```
var contents = $(divToPrint.html());
```

you can then manipulate this variable and it will update the variable, eg:

```
contents.find("span").removeClass("overflow-hidden");
```

if you use `$(contents).find...` then it will create a new jquery variable each time and update that - i.e. not update `contents`.

To get the final html:

```
sendToOutput(contents.html());
```